# How to update progress bar from other class?

Tags: c#, .net, progress-bar

I have a command line tool written in c# (that i have the source of) that I am making a gui for in visual studio 2010. In the gui I want to update the progress bar to reflect the progress of the tools operations. How would I signal from inside the tool that progress has been made and to update the progress bar?
Some simplified example code of what im doing.

```
private void doThings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  myToolInstance.doWorkThatNeedsToReportProgress();
}
```

The work that is being done by the tool is a series of function calls, normally around 30. I want to update the progress bar each time one of those finishes.

Comment: Do you have control over the source code of the command line tool?  Does the tool currently indicate progress in any way?  How?

Comment: Progress is reflected by what you're trying to accomplish. You need to find a variable reflective of the task at hand that can be monitored and updated to the progress bar. It would help if you edited your post with specifics.

Comment: Can you give us some of your code, and point out which part needs a progress bar? Also, what framework are you building your GUI in (WPF, Winforms?)?

Comment: how are you instantiating your tool?

Comment: What UI - Forms or WPF?  And why does the command line tool need to remain?  Can't you just more it all to the UI?  It is still .NET and C#.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a public property or a public method in the form containing the progress bar

```
public void SetProgress(int progress)
{
    progressBar.Progress = progress;
}
```

Now you can update the progress bar with

```
myForm.SetProgress(50);
```

---

Another approach is to have a `ProgressChanged` event somewhere and let the form subscribe to this event.

```
public class Tool {
    public event Action<int> ProgressChanged;

    private void OnProgressChanged(int progress) 
    {
        ProgressChanged?.Invoke(progress);
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        ...
        OnProgressChanged(30);
        ...
    }
}
```

In the form you would have something like this

```
private Tool _tool;

public MyForm () // Constructor of your form
{
    _tool = new Tool();
    _tool.ProgressChanged += Tool_ProgressChanged;
}

private void Tool_ProgressChanged(int progress)
{
    progressBar.Progress = progress;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that progress data comes from an external tool (running in a different process).

Comment: But it works because I can (and did) get the source for the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Golden shovel candidate, nevertheless I came across similar issue and I'd like to share my solution here.

In general, I have a method that will be run asynchronously due to computational complexity. One of the input parameters is the progress bar itself.
Since the `ProgressBar` is of nullable type, it is not mandatory when invoking the method.
Inside the method I do the progress bar advancing in its dispatcher - in many cases the method will be run on other thread that owns the progress bar. To handle the null possibility of the progress bar, I use the `nullable` operator:

```
private string MyMethod(int input, ProgressBar progressBar)
{
    while(!done)
    {
        // Do the hard work.

        progressBar?.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => progressBar.Value++);
    }
}
```

Now, I need to set the progress bar `Maxiumim` before I call the method and it must be set to the expected length.

Some may say that I'm causing great inefficiency calling the dispatcher each time I need to advance the progress bar. Yes, I agree to that, however it all depends on how many steps we need to go through. That's why I've run some quick benchmark.

For my case I had more than 300,000 (three hundred thousands) steps (each step was formatting some data to a string and writing that string to a file). Running the method without the progress bar update was my reference.

- updating progress bar **each** step made the run time longer by more than **2,000%** (twenty times longer)
- updating progress bar **every 10th step** made the run time longer by more than **250%** (two and a half times longer)
- updating progress bar **every 100th step** made the run time longer by around **15%** (longer by about 1/8th)
- updating progress bar **every 1000th step** made the run time longer by around **3%** (marginal difference)

With my progress bar being 240 pixels wide I've settled for progress bar maximum of about 300 and updating it accordingly receiving very smooth animation without noticeable performance penalty.